# Right syntax For Double Quoted JSON Value With Javascript Push

Tags: javascript, json, push, double-quotes

What would be the right syntax to cover value with double quotes to process posted one with json_decode in PHP?

```
jQuery('#envantereuruneklemediv tbody tr').each(function(index, element) {
       id=jQuery(element).find('.sec').attr('Id').split('_')[1];
    liste.push({"UrunAdi":jQuery('#uruneklemetablodiv input[name="UrunAdi_'+id).val()});
});
```

Result:

liste=[{"UrunAdi":"Value"}];

Comment: You don't have to worry about that if you serialize the JavaScript array with `JSON.stringify()` - that will ensure that all strings are properly encoded with escaped special characters.

Comment: I need to state that json_decode returns NULL, because of value is not in double quotes.

Comment: Then you're client-side code has improperly serialized the object.

Comment: Thanks for help Pointy. You are right. I have just enhanced the code. Would it be better to push values to an array, then serialize with stingify?

Comment: You have an incorrect selector _->_ `jQuery('#uruneklemetablodiv input[name="UrunAdi_'+id)`

Comment: Yes - the `JSON.stringify()` function is efficient, and it will ensure that you have valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks Rahil. You are also right. I don't know why but browsers rendered right with error. They don't care this kind of error. But I also fixed. But real metter was PHP does not parse without double quotes. I will try stringify().